# Rails new create issue with multi_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am not too sure what the initial problem is when I create new rails apps, but it seems like every time I create an application, I run into a json issue. When I do try to do a gem install the `multi_json -v '1.8.1'`, I get an error as well. It seems like the gem can't be updated because of a server issue from rubygems.org. Am I missing something?

```
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.5)
Using minitest (4.7.5)

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/gems/multi_json-1.8.1.gem)
An error occurred while installing multi_json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install multi_json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: are you on a mac? Do you use RVM to manage your rubies? That error you're getting is an SSL error which happens when your ca_certificates are outdated.

Comment: also which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: Hey Leo yes I'm on a mac and use RVM. I'm on `ruby 2.0.0p247`. Can I simply run this in my terminal to update it: `rvm osx-ssl-certs update all`

Comment: Yes that's actually the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `rvm osx-ssl-certs update all` will update outdated certificates.